# Linq query to merge overlapping elements

Tags: c#, linq

I have this class representing a period of time:

```
public class Period
{
    public Period(DateTime dateFrom)
    {
        DateFrom = dateFrom;
    }

    public Period(DateTime dateFrom, DateTime? dateTo)
    {
        DateFrom = dateFrom;
        DateTo = dateTo;
    }

    public Period() { }
    public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateTo { get; set; }


    public bool IsOverlapping(Period other)
    {
        if (!DateTo.HasValue)
        {
            return DateFrom.Value <= other.DateTo.Value;
        }
        
        if (!other.DateTo.HasValue)
        {
            return other.DateFrom.Value <= DateTo.Value;
        }

        return DateFrom.Value <= other.DateTo.Value && other.DateFrom.Value <= DateTo.Value;
    }

    public bool IsFinite => DateTo.HasValue;

    public bool IsInfinite => !IsFinite;

    // Equals/GetHashCode have been overrided
}
```

Now a have a list of periods and for each of them I have to perform an network call so to minimize them I decide to merge all overlapping periods.

So a list like that :

- 2020-01-01 -> 2020-01-10
- 2020-02-05 -> 2020-02-10
- 2020-02-07 -> 2020-02-15
- 2020-02-13 -> 2020-02-20
- 2020-03-01 -> 2020-03-10
- 2020-03-25 -> 2020-03-31
- 2020-03-30 ->

Should become :

- 2020-01-01 -> 2020-01-10
- 2020-02-05 -> 2020-02-20
- 2020-03-01 -> 2020-03-10
- 2020-03-25 ->

I tried this code

```
    periods.OrderBy(p => p.DateFrom.Value)
            .Aggregate(new List<Period>(), (ps, p) =>
            {
                if (!ps.Any())
                {
                    ps.Add(p);
                    return ps;
                }

                var last = ps.Last();
                if (last.IsOverlapping(p))
                {
                    if (last.IsInfinite || p.IsInfinite)
                    {
                        ps[ps.Count() - 1] = new Period(DateTimeHelpers.Min(last.DateFrom.Value, p.DateFrom.Value), null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ps[ps.Count() - 1] = new Period(DateTimeHelpers.Min(last.DateFrom.Value, p.DateFrom.Value), DateTimeHelpers.Max(last.DateTo.Value, p.DateTo.Value));
                    }

                    return ps;
                }

                ps.Add(p);
                return ps;

            });
```

It's working properly but I'm not satisfied with it so I wonder if there is a more performant/elegant/readable way to do it ?

I'm not talking about just refactoring to extract some methods but a fundamentally different solution, it's possible I missed a useful LINQ operator.

Here is my test if you want to reproduce it (MsTest + FluentAssertions). The period are not in the right order to ensure it will be take care of by the method itself:

```
        // Arrange
        var periods = new List<Period>()
        {
            new Period(new DateTime(2020, 2, 13), new DateTime(2020, 2, 20)),
            new Period(new DateTime(2020, 3, 1), new DateTime(2020, 3, 10)),
            new Period(new DateTime(2020, 3, 25), new DateTime(2020, 3, 31)),
            new Period(new DateTime(2020, 3, 30)),
            new Period(new DateTime(2020, 1, 1), new DateTime(2020, 1, 10)),
            new Period(new DateTime(2020, 2, 5), new DateTime(2020, 2, 10)),
            new Period(new DateTime(2020, 2, 7), new DateTime(2020, 2, 15))
        };

        // Act
        var mergedPeriods = Implementation(periods);

        // Assert
        mergedPeriods.Should().HaveCount(4);
        mergedPeriods[0].Should().Be(new Period(new DateTime(2020, 1, 1), new DateTime(2020, 1, 10)));
        mergedPeriods[1].Should().Be(new Period(new DateTime(2020, 2, 5), new DateTime(2020, 2, 20)));
        mergedPeriods[2].Should().Be(new Period(new DateTime(2020, 3, 1), new DateTime(2020, 3, 10)));
        mergedPeriods[3].Should().Be(new Period(new DateTime(2020, 3, 25)));
```

Comment: Might be better asked on codereview.stackexchange.com. I don't see anything particularly LINQ-y about this code, although the empty list aggregation is neat. A shorter version: https://pastebin.com/cSyhSBkX

Comment: I know great library which do that with ease. Overlapping, concatenation, intersection, etc. If you interested in I'll prepare sample.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv If you have a link to the library or its documentation it would be helpful :-)

Comment: Well library is: https://github.com/rsdn/CodeJam, key to search is `CompositeRange` and  `Merge`, other available operations you can find yourself. Create `CompositeRange` with enumeration of ranges and `Merge`. It is common task when dealing with such structures, so this part of the library is born.